# JNA has a main Class that does not match the declared Main

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, javafx-8, jna

For OCR functionality I have used jna.jar. When I am trying to generate the .dmg or .exe [in Eclipse] file then the build goes successful but it doesn't generate the .dmg or .exe because of the below error:

```
The jar libs/jna.jar has a main class com.sun.jna.Native that does not match the declared main xx.xxxx.xxx.MainAppClass
The jar libs/jna.jar has a main class com.sun.jna.Native that does not match the declared main xx.xxxx.xxx.MainAppClass
Bundler DMG Installer skipped because of a configuration problem: Main application jar is missing.  
Advice to fix: Make sure to use fx:jar task to create main application jar.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JNA has a main class that doesn't match the declared main class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197568/jna-has-a-main-class-that-doesnt-match-the-declared-main-class)

Comment: exactly thats my question.